# Smart client data source rebind

Tags: datasource, smartclient, listgrid

I created a smartclient data source and list grid. The autoFetchData is set to false and the list grid dataSource is set to my data source.

When I do a search I set the data source dataURL to my url and call the list grid fetchData method.

```
var url = "myurl?value=123";
deploymentDataSource.dataURL = url;
deploymentList.fetchData();
```

This works fine and the list grid displays the values correctly.

The problem is when I try and do a search again with new parameters it does not update my list grid with the new values.

```
var url = "myurl?value=456";
deploymentDataSource.dataURL = url;
deploymentList.fetchData();
```

Here is my data source and list grid:

```
isc.DataSource.create({
    ID: "deploymentDataSource",
    dataFormat: "json",
    fields: [
        {name: "id", title: "id"},
        {name: "date", title: "date"},
        {name: "buildNumber", title: "buildNumber"},
        {name: "projectKey", title: "projectKey"},
        {name: "planKey", title: "planKey"},
        {name: "buildEnvironment", title: "buildEnvironment"}
    ]
});


isc.ListGrid.create({
    ID: "deploymentList",
    width: 600, height: 300, alternateRecordStyles: true,
    dataSource: "deploymentDataSource",
    selectionType: "simple",
    autoFetchData: false
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call this after changing the `DataSource.dataURL`

```
ListGrid.invalidateCache();
```

and you don't need to call `ListGrid.fetchData()` again

Reference:
http://www.smartclient.com/docs/release/a/b/c/go.html#method..ListGrid.invalidateCache

Comment: This should work; but if not there may be other settings getting in the way.  Some grids will not refresh like this.  I have had to move to manual insertion in some cases. Us the JSON request to retrieve the data then setDate({}).

Comment: Calling ListGrid.invalidateCache() and then ListGrid.fetchData() worked, thanks